# New configurations added from Yocto project menuconfig don't take place in the released linux image

Tags: menu, linux-kernel, config, embedded-linux, yocto

I'm using **yocto project** to build a customized **linux image** for my **sama5d27-som1-ek1** board.

I used **MENUCONFIG** to add some configurations to my linux kernel which i need in my board.

1. I selected with "y" what i want to add from MENUCONFIG : **USERSPACE LEDS SUPPORT**
2. I saved.
3. I was asked to put a name for the new configuration file before i
   exit
4. I re-build the kernel.

The problem is : When i checked the config file again under this path: */poky/build-microchip/tmp/work/sama5d27_som1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-at91/4.14+gitAUTOINC+b733e44da2-r0/image/boot/ config-4.14.73-linux4sam-6.0-dirty*

i found that no modifications happened and what i want to add did not take place!

> CONFIG_LEDS_USER is not set

I verified the MENUCONFIG again and i found that USERSPACE LED SUPPORT is checked.

What I am missing here ? How can configurations take place ?

Comment: How have you rebuilt the kernel? If you clean the project/kernel your new config file could be cleaned as well. You should generate a "kernel configuration fragment file" holding the modifications and add it to your kernel recipe in order to make the changes persistent. Alternatively, if you are just experimenting and don't plan to make the changes persistent yet, you should care about your new config when you rebuild the kernel. For furhter information, take a look over https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/kernel-dev/kernel-dev.html#configuring-the-kernel

Comment: I followed the steps described here : https://www.at91.com/linux4sam/bin/view/Linux4SAM/Sama5d27Som1EKMainPage ..  under 'Configure and Build the Linux kernel' title. So : 1/ make ARCH=arm sama5_defconfig  2/ make ARCH=arm menuconfig ( to make modifications )  3/set up the cross compile toolchain  4/make ARCH=arm  5/make ARCH=arm dtbs  6/Bitbake core-image-minimal ( to rebuild all the image )